# SQL - get several occurences for each value with DISTINCT or GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

with DISTINCT or GROUP BY a record for each value (or set of values) can be taken like in the query below:

```
SELECT id, MAX(price) FROM Products GROUP BY id
```

The result will be something like:

```
ID | price
1    10
2    11
```

Is it possible to have, for example, 3 different prices for each ID ?

Comment: how people can know this if you not share the scenario with data example

Comment: If you group by id, you'll only get each id once. What is the reason you're asking this?

Comment: Hi @HoneyBadger, i'm asking becouse i need some price examples from each id. this is the scenario.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin don't seems so important the scenario, developers below has some solutions. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using self join

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71f58cc5fae2086b962725466ea08599)**

```
SELECT Products.id, Products.price,COUNT(p.price) AS rank
FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN Products AS p ON Products.id = p.id AND Products.price< p.price
GROUP BY Products.id, Products.price
HAVING COUNT(p.price) < 3
ORDER BY Products.id, Products.price DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. solution is working fine! thanks also for the dbfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` if you want to get all the values, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(price)
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your MySql version supports Window functions you can use RANK() and PARTITION

```
SELECT id, price
FROM (SELECT id, price, RANK() OVER w as price_rank
      FROM test
      WINDOW w as (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY price desc)) r
WHERE price_rank <= 3 
ORDER BY id, price desc
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the three highest prices is to use `group_concat()` and `substring_index()`:

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price DESC), ',' 3) as top3_prices
FROM Products
GROUP BY id;
```